# DistinctBy With Condition in LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq, morelinq

I am having entity collection from Database which contains certain duplicates like One sequence with values and other sequence with empty values. I would like to remove sequence with empty one. I have tired `moreLINQ` for `DistinctBy` but still my case is not satisfying.

I have a following list from result set.

```
Result: Id=1, Name="Test1", Status="New", Values=NULL 
Result: Id=1, Name="Test1", Status="Assigned", Values=123 
Result: Id=2, Name="Test2", Status="New", Values=NULL 
Result: Id=2, Name="Test2", Status="Assigned", Values=698 
Result: Id=3, Name="Test3", Status="Assigned", Values=569 
Result: Id=4, Name="Test4", Status="New", Values=NULL 
Result: Id=5, Name="Test5", Status="Assigned", Values=156
```

I would like to retrieve follwoing outputs always by skipping duplicate with empty values or `New` status.

```
Result: Id=1, Name="Test1", Status="Assigned", Values=123 
Result: Id=2, Name="Test2", Status="Assigned", Values=698 
Result: Id=3, Name="Test3", Status="Assigned", Values=569 
Result: Id=4, Name="Test4", Status="New", Values=NULL 
Result: Id=5, Name="Test5", Status="Assigned", Values=156
```

Comment: `.Where(x=>x.Status=="Assigned")` should do the job.

Comment: @MaciejLos That's my wrong. I have updated the question now. I want New Status as well when its unique

Answer (score 0):

You can so something like below

[DOTNETFIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vog2Ua) working code

```
var modified = listOfValues
                .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(x => x.Values ?? int.MinValue).FirstOrDefault());
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Ordering before grouping may not always give the expected results. Also, as OP said in the comment, `Status` is the determining property, not `Values`.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but my understanding is if there is any record with some value he wants to retrieve that else the record with status `New`

Comment: @GertArnold Removed OrderBy before Grouping as suggested, thanks

Comment: @GertArnold, I also considered Ordering based on the Values because they are numeric and ordering on the numeric will be faster than the strings

Answer (score 0):

Group by `Id` and take the first record of each group that is ordered by `Status`:

```cs
var records = new[]
{
    (Id:1, Name:"Test1", Status:"New", Values:default(int?)),
    (Id:1, Name:"Test1", Status:"Assigned", Values:123),
    (Id:2, Name:"Test2", Status:"New", Values:default(int?)),
    (Id:2, Name:"Test2", Status:"Assigned", Values:698),
    (Id:3, Name:"Test3", Status:"Assigned", Values:569),
    (Id:4, Name:"Test4", Status:"New", Values:default(int?)),
    (Id:5, Name:"Test5", Status:"Assigned", Values:156),
};

var result = records
    .GroupBy(r => r.Id)
    .Select(r => r.OrderBy(x => x.Status).First());
```

Result:

```
Id  Name    Status      Values
------------------------------
1   Test1   Assigned    123
2   Test2   Assigned    698
3   Test3   Assigned    569
4   Test4   New         null
5   Test5   Assigned    156
```